# How to remove areas of overlap within the same layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, overlay

I'm currently working with some data on soil survey areas in the US, and have run into a small issue when intersecting this data with another set of parcel areas.

The problem appears to be that there are smaller soil areas within larger soil areas, and when intersecting this layer with the other parcels, the total area of intersection includes both the entire larger area plus the smaller area, leaving me with a total greater than 100% of the original parcel. This inner area may also have different soil qualities than the outer area, which is what I need to measure, so I essentially need to be able to 'cut out' the smaller area from the larger one, and keep only the smaller area and its data in that space.

To combat this I've tried using the 'overlay_within' function, to identify the smaller interior areas, but due to the data's size (all of Massachusetts), QGIS runs forever when trying to execute. I'm not sure if my best option is to use a different function, or to just try leaving my machine on for a day.

In the image below I tried to highlight this (the soil areas are in red, and parcels in blue). The smaller red area (underlined with yellow) fits into the larger area, and the intersection with the blue area gives it the entire area of the outer red area, plus the inner red area, leaving me with a total intersection area greater than the initial parcel size.

[image: Here's an image to explain the situation]

Comment: Assuming you have no overlapping polygons in your in put layers, if you run an overlay, such as an intersection, and recalculate your area fields in the resulting layer, you should get correct results.  If one or both of your inputs have overlapping polygons you could run a v.clean (GRASS tool) on them followed by deleting duplicate geometries tool, that should get rid of duplicates, but where there is overlap the choice of which one to keep is "random" from your point of view., so you may need to do some manual editing.